# copying list of structs in common lisp

Tags: list, struct, copy, common-lisp, pass-by-value

I have a list of structs, and I want to write a function that alters some slots in the structs without affecting the original list. I tried using copy-list, but its not deep enough; the slot values are also altered in the original list. My question is, is there a built-in function that does what I want?, or should I write my own one?. Thank you.

EDIT:

I went on and wrote my own function, is there a built-in one that would do this though?

```
(defun deep-copy (li)
    (if (null li)
        nil
        (cons (copy-structure (car li)) (deep-copy (rest li)))))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is little value to have that function pre-defined.

Your code is just:

```
(mapcar #'copy-structure some-list)
```

Comment: AAAahhhhhh, you are right :D. That was a dumb question, it was very late at night though :D. Thanks a lot for taking time to answer this.